# Why does it take a very long time to loop through the pymongo.cursor.Cursor object, even there is no data in that object?

Tags: python, algorithm, mongodb, optimization, pymongo

For example, I have this code in my python file:

```
    kpidata=db.kpidata

    start=time.time()

    starttime="06:00:00"
    endtime="06:10:00"
    demodate="10/05/2016"



    for min in kpidata.find():  
        print min

    print(time.time()-start)
```

Suppose kpidata.find() will give an empty Cursor object, but looping through it, or even converting that into a list--list(kpidata.find()) will take lots of time. In my case, it took me more that 4 seconds.

Can anybody explain why?

Lastest code update:

```
from QuerylocationITE import *
from QuerylocationCRAC import *
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
from datetime import *
import os
import glob
import time

kpidata=db.kpidata

starttime="06:00:00"
endtime="06:10:00"
demodate="10/05/2016"
print("\n\n\n\n\n\n")
start=time.time()
store=kpidata.find({"voltage":"-100"}).batch_size(1000)
print(store.count())

print(time.time()-start)
print("\n")
start=time.time()

count=0
for min in store:
    count=count+1

print(time.time()-start)
print("\n")
start=time.time()
list(store)


print(time.time()-start)
```

and the output is 0,4.25277400017,4.11696910858,1.00135803223e-05

any thoughts, now I guess it took a lot of time of querying the data for database

Comment: How is it supposed to know that the cursor is empty without taking time to query the database? In this case, it takes more than four seconds.

Comment: Oh sorry to mention that kpidata.find() doesn't take long, just a few microseconds, and I tested the whether the cursor is empty or not by using count().

Comment: I had assumed it was a case of the cursor being lazy, i.e., not actually doing anything until you started iterating over it. But it would have to iterate to get a count, too, so... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It shouldn't take that long. Try debugging piece by piece, 1) mongodb - analyse logs, [check profiling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/), 2) network - I don't see your `MongoClient()`, but is it remote/local host connection 3) python - It doesn't look like its your full code, you have random imports etc. strip it all down, this test should be about ~7 lines including imports.